# Is it possible to work with Microsoft Sharepoint with Go?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, go

I want to know is any library to work with Microsoft Sharepoint ?
Can we program with go language for Microsoft Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint is many things and it is unclear what you mean by "Can we program with Go for Sharepoint", but you may want to take a look at [Sharepoint 2013 apps](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/an-overview-of-sharepoint-2013-app-development-model/), which will support "Self-Hosted Apps", that could be written in any language. From the linked article:

```
You could be a PHP developer with a Linux machine and still make SharePoint apps.
```

If you're more interested in interacting with Sharepoint's APIs, it looks like [Sharepoint 2013 provides a RESTful API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/fp179930.aspx#SPappoverview_howtalk), so again, no problem for Go.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Unfortunately, googling for such library was not successful in my case.

Q2: If MS Sharepoint (whatever that is) has some known or documented API or it can be accessed by some known or documented protocol(s) then the answer is definitely yes.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this will not be possible. Sharepoint as far as I know is an ASP.NET application designed for the Microsoft IIS platform and depends on the closed-source .NET framework.

Working with Sharepoint over APIs though, should be possible but judging by your question I don't think that's what you want.